How does raising a complex number to n affect its principal argument
Suppose we have a complex number, z = 1 + i and we define its principal argument to be -$\pi$ < $\theta$ <$\pi$.
What happens to our principal argument in the case that $z^5$ = $(1 + i)^5$?
Does our principal argument change to become $5\pi$ < $5\theta$ < $5\pi$, and does our $\theta$ obey $\pi$ < $\theta$ <$\pi$. However, when we look at $e^{\textstyle\sqrt2 \frac{ 5\pi}{ 4}}$, we look at our $\theta$ as being $\frac{\pi}{4}$ that happens to fall in our range and is in the 1st quadrant but since we multiply it by 5 we get an entirely different complex number in the 3rd quadrant.
I've tried to articulate my issue as best as possible, but what I'll reiterate once again that I would like to know how changing our z affects our principal argument.

Yes, your posted analysis is accurate, and is consistent with De Moivre's formula.
Specifically, $~\displaystyle \left[ ~re^{i\theta} ~\right]^5 = r^5 \times e^{i5\theta}.$
Your only mis-step seems to be that since [when $~z = (1 + i) $], you have that $~\displaystyle r = \sqrt{2},~$ then you have $~\displaystyle r^5 = \sqrt{2} ~{}^5 = 4\sqrt{2}.$
